# Extract images of sand dunes migration from 1st January 2021 to 20th December 2023 through Landsat9

Tags: landsat, image-segmentation

I'm seeking to extract images depicting the migration of sand dunes between January 1, 2021, and December 20, 2023, utilizing Landsat 9 data. While attempting to retrieve this information using the provided code, I encountered an issue where it doesn't seem to provide any response. I've identified the specific location of interest (ROI) that I can easily map. How can I properly set the parameters to retrieve data illustrating the movement of sand dunes during this time frame?

Code used -

```js
var roi = 
    /* color: #d63000 */
    /* locked: true */
    /* displayProperties: [
      {
        "type": "rectangle"
      },
      {
        "type": "rectangle"
      },
      {
        "type": "rectangle"
      },
      {
        "type": "rectangle"
      },
      {
        "type": "rectangle"
      },
      {
        "type": "rectangle"
      },
      {
        "type": "rectangle"
      },
      {
        "type": "rectangle"
      },
      {
        "type": "rectangle"
      },
      {
        "type": "rectangle"
      },
      {
        "type": "rectangle"
      }
    ] */
    ee.Geometry.MultiPolygon(
        [[[[70.337795541492, 27.576659920972695],
           [70.337795541492, 25.720938254177714],
           [72.568020150867, 25.720938254177714],
           [72.568020150867, 27.576659920972695]]],
         [[[72.52034863432827, 28.77237110987351],
           [72.52034863432827, 27.00519755374891],
           [74.98128613432827, 27.00519755374891],
           [74.98128613432827, 28.77237110987351]]],
         [[[71.09212597807827, 27.766086590186497],
           [71.09212597807827, 27.376540931392064],
           [73.02571972807827, 27.376540931392064],
           [73.02571972807827, 27.766086590186497]]],
         [[[70.78450879057827, 25.962877830340403],
           [70.78450879057827, 25.388591755188383],
           [71.99300488432827, 25.388591755188383],
           [71.99300488432827, 25.962877830340403]]],
         [[[69.88362988432827, 27.239874120877815],
           [69.88362988432827, 26.632623546533452],
           [70.63070019682827, 26.632623546533452],
           [70.63070019682827, 27.239874120877815]]],
         [[[72.03695019682827, 28.13486823736629],
           [72.03695019682827, 27.64936818897948],
           [72.65218457182827, 27.64936818897948],
           [72.65218457182827, 28.13486823736629]]],
         [[[70.30111035307827, 27.72719433336178],
           [70.30111035307827, 27.43506084269581],
           [70.69661816557827, 27.43506084269581],
           [70.69661816557827, 27.72719433336178]]],
         [[[70.21321972807827, 27.39605101150761],
           [70.21321972807827, 27.024772724046876],
           [70.67464550932827, 27.024772724046876],
           [70.67464550932827, 27.39605101150761]]],
         [[[69.92757519682827, 27.39605101150761],
           [69.92757519682827, 27.0443444836511],
           [70.71859082182827, 27.0443444836511],
           [70.71859082182827, 27.39605101150761]]],
         [[[69.68587597807827, 27.16170332225251],
           [69.68587597807827, 26.75041073870381],
           [69.90560254057827, 26.75041073870381],
           [69.90560254057827, 27.16170332225251]]],
         [[[70.93831738432827, 25.448128715371883],
           [70.93831738432827, 24.891312810466758],
           [71.50960644682827, 24.891312810466758],
           [71.50960644682827, 25.448128715371883]]]], null, false);
```

```js
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC09/C02/T1_L2')
    .filterDate('2022-01-01', '2023-12-20')
    .filterBounds(roi);
    
    // Function to calculate Normalized Difference Vegetation Index (NDVI)
    var addNDVI = function(image) {
      var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['B5', 'B4']).rename('NDVI');
      return image.addBands(ndvi);
    };
    
    // Map the function over the collection to add NDVI band
    var landsat9WithNDVI = dataset.map(addNDVI);
    // Select images with low NDVI values (indicating potential dune areas)
    var potentialDunes = landsat9WithNDVI.filter(ee.Filter.lt('NDVI', 0.2));

    
    // Check if there are images in the potential dunes collection
    var sampleImage = ee.Image(ee.Algorithms.If(
      potentialDunes.size().gt(0),
      potentialDunes.first(),
      ee.Image().select() // Empty image if no potential dune images found
    ));
    
    // Display the potential dunes image on the map if it exists
    if (sampleImage.bandNames().size().gt(0)) {
      Map.centerObject(roi, 8);
      Map.addLayer(sampleImage, {bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], max: 3000}, 'Potential Dunes');
    } else {
      print("No potential dune images found in the specified date range and region.");
    }
```

Comment: You don't tell us what the ROI is so we can't check the first thing with this code. Can you add that to the code block?

Comment: update roi for reference